# Cannot align contents of div to the left in Edge

Tags: html, css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

We have a side menu where each list item contains an image and text which should be aligned to the left. It looks fine in Google Chrome, but IE and Edge render differently. I don't mind IE not working (I may try coming back to that at a later date) but Edge needs to work as expected.

I have tried using `justify-content: flex-start` on the `<a>` tag after changing it to `display: flex` which usually works but not in this situation.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 230px;
}

#sidebar ul {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sidebar li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sidebar ul a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  width: 155px;
  min-width: 155px;
}

#sidebar ul a img {
  margin: 0 15px 0 4px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 21px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UU5GJm7.png" >
        <span>Super Long Account Name</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's how the code renders in Chrome vs Edge:

[image: Screenshot Comparison]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I took a pass at removing unused CSS rules and irrelevant dom nodes/attributes just by reordering elements in chrome dev tools or removing rulesets to see if they materially affected the positioning issue - everything else can be entirely removed to get to the *minimal* reproducible example.  These are good things to do before posting, but just good debugging first steps as well for you to consider.

Comment: Try adding `text-align: center` on the *span* (`#sidebar span`).

Comment: @KyleMit Thanks for that. I was scared to touch anything. Appreciated. I was worried in case it no longer reflected the real scenario.

Comment: @Brhaka didn't work. The text still needs to be aligned left though. It seems to be a problem with the image as the image is too far right but yet has no left margin or padding. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `white-space: pre-wrap;` is causing your issues

Try removing all instances of it (from selectors like the following):

```css
#sidebar ul a {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 230px;
}

#sidebar ul {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sidebar li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sidebar ul a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  width: 155px;
  min-width: 155px;
}

#sidebar ul a img {
  margin: 0 15px 0 4px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 21px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UU5GJm7.png" >
        <span>Super Long Account Name</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So that worked, but when I was unchecking that style in the Edge inspection window it didn't seem to change anything (when on the real website) so that let me to believe that wasn't the issue but once I removed it from the CSS and reloaded it worked. Thanks!

Comment: It's likely because there were a lot of duplicate selectors and rulesets in your stylesheet.  So unchecking it from one likely means it's still being applied by another.  You can check the "Computed" properties tab to double check

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `white-space: pre-wrap;` from `#sidebar ul a` style.. It will fix your issue.

See the Snippet below

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 230px;
}

#sidebar ul {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sidebar li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sidebar ul a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  /*white-space: pre-wrap;*/
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  width: 155px;
  min-width: 155px;
}

#sidebar ul a img {
  margin: 0 15px 0 4px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 21px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UU5GJm7.png" >
        <span>Super Long Account Name</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. @KyleMit beat you to it but still very appreciated!

Comment: by few seconds ;)

Comment: Parallel thinking - both of us were within seconds, and both spent a non-zero amount of time diagnosing